# Setting up multiple grids in Ganglia

Tags: ganglia

Has anyone set up multiple grids to show on a single UI with Ganglia? I know how to set up multiple clusters but would love to show Grids on one interface.

Here's an example.

http://ganglia.g.gsic.titech.ac.jp/ganglia/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To form a grid of grids you simply point at a `gmetad` rather than a `gmond` as a `data_source` in `gmetad.conf`.

The child `gmetad` must have `xml_port` enabled and that is the port you use in the `data_source`.

Comment: Thanks, for the remote `gmetad` I'm polling, do I need to install ganglia-web on it? I was under the assumption I can have a bunch of `gmetad` servers where I can pull data from on the main `gmetad` server that has the web UI. If I click on the "grid" name for the other `gmetad` server, it wants to display its UI.

Comment: The web interface and the RRDs (and hence gmetad) have to be on the same server. Be sure to set the `authority` URL in gmetad.conf for the child grid correctly.

Comment: Sorry let me clarify, I have the web interface and RRDs on the central server. I also have a bunch of other gmetad (the other grids) on various servers. Do I need a web interface on EACH gmetad server?

Comment: If you want to see details about the clusters on the child grids then yes, you need the web interface on each gmetad server. Look at it this way: The web interface queries gmetads for information about the clusters/grids they are polling but reads the rrd data (via rrdtool) directly from the local filesystem.